# How does process-environment get initialized and why would it be different from initial-environment?

Tags: environment, exec-path

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with my `exec-path`. It contains a couple of paths prepended to it that I don't want. `initial-environment` contains the paths that match what I see when I echo `$PATH` in xterm but `process-environment` contains a couple extra and I can't figure out how they are getting there.

I've tried setting a watcher with`debug-on-variable-change` at the start of my init.el file, but by the time the watcher gets triggered, `process-environment` already has those 2 garbage entries. Can I set that watch before Emacs launches?

Answer (score 2):

The C function `set_initial_environment` in `callproc.c` populates `process-environment` and `initial-environment` together.  Subsequent calls to `setenv` are the *usual* way of modifying `process-environment` (but noting that it's very common to be doing that in only a temporary dynamic scope).  Obviously it's just a list though, so other manipulations are also entirely possible.

> Is there a way to watch a variable and enter a debugger when it is changed?

Yes, see: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Watching Variables`

> Can I set that watch before Emacs launches?

There is nothing to set or watch before Emacs launches.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is related to Doom Emacs. I should have included in my original question that I was using a Doom config.

The reason my initial attempt at putting a `debug-on-variable-change` in my `init.el` didn't work was because I was putting it in `.doom.d/init.el` which is loaded late in the initialization process. After reading the Doom docs about the initialization order, I saw that it starts with `.emacs.d/init.el` (of course). I put the `debug-on-variable-change` in there and saw it was happening in the function `(doom-load-envvars-file "~/.emacs.d/.local/env")` which gets called as part of Doom's initialization.

```
# -*- mode: sh -*-
# Generated from a /bin/zsh shell environent
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This file was auto-generated by `doom env'. It contains a list of environment
# variables scraped from your default shell (excluding variables blacklisted
# in doom-env-ignored-vars).
#
# It is NOT safe to edit this file. Changes will be overwritten next time you
# run 'doom sync'. To create a safe-to-edit envvar file use:
#
#   doom env -o ~/.doom.d/myenv
#
# And load it with (doom-load-envvars-file "~/.doom.d/myenv").
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just needed to run `doom sync` from a terminal that had the environment that I wanted.